# Selenium to push button in form

Tags: python, selenium

Python: 3.4.1
Browser: Chrome

I'm trying to push a button which is located in a form using Selenium with Python. I'm fairly new to Selenium and HTML.

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<FORM id='QLf_437222' method='POST' action='xxxx'>
    <script>document.write("<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='document.getElementById(\"QLf_437222\").submit();' title='xxx'>51530119</a>");</script>
    <noscript><INPUT type='SUBMIT' value='51530119' title='xxx' name='xxxx'></noscript>                             
    <INPUT type=hidden name="prodType" value="DDA"/>
    <INPUT type=hidden name="BlitzToken" value="BlitzToken"/>
    <INPUT type=hidden name="productInfo" value="40050951530119"/>
    <INPUT type=hidden name="reDirectionURL" value="xxx"/>          
</FORM>
```

I've been trying the following:

```
driver.execute("javascript:void(0)")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="QLf_437104"]/a').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="QLf_437104"]/a').submit()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#QLf_437104 > a").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#QLf_437104 > a").submit()
```

Python doesn't throw an exception, so it seems like I'm clicking something, but it doesn't do what I want.

In addition to this the webpage acts funny when the chrome driver is initialized from Selenium. When clicking the button in the initialized chrome driver, the webpage throws an error (888).

I'm not sure where to go from here. Might it be something with the hidden elements?

If I can provide additional information please let me know.

EDIT:

It looks like the form id changes sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it sounds like you are trying to do, is to submit the form, right?

The `<a>` that you are pointing out is simply submitting that form.  Since that  is being injected via JavaScript, it's possible that it's not showing up when you try to click it.  What i'd recommend, is doing:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form[id^='QLf']").submit()
```

That will avoid the button, and submit the appropriate form.

In the above CSS selector, i also used `[id^=` this means, find a `<form>` with an ID attribute that *starts with* QLf, because it looks like the numbers after, are automatically generated.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. Python does "something" and doesn't throw an exception. But the form is not submitted.

Comment: also take out `driver.execute("javascript:void(0)")` that is doing *nothing*

Comment: It looks like selenium can't locate the element after all. The form id changes randomly.

Comment: if it's the number that is changing randomly, then you need to use `form[id^='QLf']`.  That means `find a form that has an ID that *starts with* "QLf"`

Comment: Nice, it works perfectly now. Thank you so much. Can you post your comment as an answer?